# SVG performance difference: changing transform or changing path

Tags: svg, raphael

I have an SVG path with 100 points (each point with "Lx y"). The path moves on mouse drag (no rotation structure change, just translation and scale).
Does anybody know: is there any performance difference between changing entire path string on each step and changing just transform matrix?

It's just more convenient for the underlying code to change entire path than transform matrix, so i wonder if i should be worried.

The code is being implemented using Raphaeljs, but i don't think it matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any performance measurements of the two variants for your particular use-case?

Comment: @ErikDahlström, no. I decided to ask here first. Moreover i don't know how browsers render SVG. This knowledge can help writing relevant benchmarks. Since the question is not that critical for me at the moment - i'm not writing benchmarks yet.

Comment: I'd bet that there is a performance difference, but there are too many unknowns to answer in more detail than that.

Comment: Personally I'd get it all working correct first, and worry about performance after as a general policy. Maybe even keep a doc/list of areas you suspect maybe good places to look for optimisations as you go, and then you can reference those later. But don't get bogged down in performance issues at first, as often methods will change as the project evolves.

Comment: @ErikDahlström, yes, you're probably right. I was just wondering if there's some general answer or a piece of advice on this topic.

Comment: @Ian, you're definitely right about avoiding premature optimisation and it's not actually a case at the moment, but this knowledge would be valuable. Moreover if you could choose between two nearly same approaches with different performance impact - you would probably like to choose the better one in the very beginning :)

Comment: there is no distinct performance difference. the two ways has same computation quantity.